# Not able to get ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am not able to get ng-repeat (ng-repeat="a in student.store") to work .It is not throwing any error but at the same time it is not rendering any output. Please suggest .

==============================

## my Angular code

```
var module = angular.module('MyApp', [])
                    .controller('MyController', function ($http, $scope) {
                        $http.get('/Department/getDept').success(function (response) {
                            $scope.departments =$scope.$eval(response);
                        });

                        $http.get('/Department/getStudents').success(function (resp) {
                            $scope.students = $scope.$eval(resp);
                        });

                        $scope.student = function(id)
                        {

                            var studentsInThatDepartment;
                            angular.forEach($scope.students, function (item) {
                                if (item.departmentId == id)
                                {
                                    studentsInThatDepartment = item;
                                }                            
                            })
                           $scope.store = angular.toJson(studentsInThatDepartment);
                            //return store;

                        }


=======================================================
mvc controller code
========================================================

public JsonResult getDept()
        {
            testdb_1Entities db = new testdb_1Entities();
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.tbl_departments.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList()),
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };

        }

        public JsonResult getStudents()
        {
            testdb_1Entities db = new testdb_1Entities();
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.tbl_students.OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList()),
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };

        }

==========================================
Index.cshtml code
==========================================

 <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="a in student.store" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                                <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
                                <td>{{a.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{a.firstName}}</td>
                                <td>{{a.lastName}}</td>
                                <td>{{a.gender}}</td>
                                <td>{{a.departmentId}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: `student` is a method which accepts an id ? But you are not calling it like a method. It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: actually it is passing department id to student function and expects to search students in that department...And i am not able to display those students result back on client.

Comment: where is it passing the department id in your view code ?

Comment: Please have a look..... from here i am passing id                                                                                                    <tbody ng-repeat="O in departments">
                <tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                    <td class="CX" ng-click="student(O.ID)"><span>+</span></td>
                    <td>{{O.ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{O.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{O.Location}}</td>
                </tr>

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a non-existing object: student.store hierarchy does not exist in your code, because your array(?) "store" it's assigned directly to the scope ( `$scope.store` ).

**What you can do is** (other than clearify your code):

to use ng-repeat over students (`<tr ng-repeat="a in students ...> </tr>`). Probably, this is the collection you need (considering your usage of `{{a.firstName}}` etc).

or

to use ng-repeat over store, but in the form  `<tr ng-repeat= "(key, value) in store" ...> </tr>` (but that's would be weird: why not using {{store.myProperty}} then?

Comment: i want to use collection inside 'store' model as view for my ng-repeat...but i am doing some mistake in (ng-repeat="a in student.store") . Please suggest

Comment: Where is this collection? how its named? can you post an example of store object?

Comment: store is not an object..its the model for my view ...its in json format.i want to use ng-repeat over 'store' . All is fine except i am not able to use 'store' in my ng-repeat.

Comment: Okay fine.. can you please show the "Store" json content to us?

Comment: [{"EmployeeProjectMappingID":2,"EmployeeID":683049,"ProjectID":1,"StartDate":"2016-01-08T10:34:09","EndDate":"2016-01-10T10:34:09","RoleID":3,"EmployeeDetail":null,"ProjectDetail":null,"UserRole":null},{"EmployeeProjectMappingID":3,"EmployeeID":683052,"ProjectID":1,"StartDate":"2016-08-29T00:00:00","EndDate":"2016-09-29T00:00:00","RoleID":3,"EmployeeDetail":null,"ProjectDetail":null,"UserRole":null}]

Comment: Maybe i don't still get your issue, but you should be able to use your collection "store" as ng-repeat="currstore in store" and then {{store.EmployeeID}}, for example.